# Double superscript error

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I'm a relative beginner with Lyx. When I type in this code I'm hoping for T' to be followed by superscripts and subscripts. Instead I get a "double superscript" error when I try to view the pdf

```
\[
T'_{\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}\ldots\alpha_{n}}^{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\ldots\mu_{m}}
\]
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can insert `\prime` symbol as part of the superscript `^{...}`, rather than having "two superscripts":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  T_{\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}\ldots\alpha_{n}}^{\prime\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\ldots\mu_{m}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. This was the solution that worked best for me. \prime gives a nice clear symbol as well, much nicer than '.

Answer (score 39):

`'` in math mode expands to `^\prime`, so your code is equivalent to `T^{\prime}_{...}^{...}`, which explains the error you get. You can either swap sub- and superscripts to be `T'^{...}_{...}` (`'` is defined in a way that merges it with an adjacent superscript), or use `\prime` inside the superscript as suggested in Werner's answer, so both

```
T'^{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\ldots\mu_{m}}_{\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}\ldots\alpha_{n}}
```

and

```
T_{\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}\ldots\alpha_{n}}^{\prime\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\ldots\mu_{m}}
```

are valid.

Answer (score 25):

In mathmode, `'` acts like `^\prime`. So you have two superscripts, which isn't allowed. One way around this is to group the `T'` like so:

```
\[
{T'}_{\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}\ldots\alpha_{n}}^{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\ldots\mu_{m}}
\]
```

But this doesn't look good. I'd suggest maybe replacing `T'` with some other variable name…

As Khaled has pointed out, this solution breaks the horizontal positioning of subscripts:

[image: broken placement of subscripts]

The top one is my grouping solution, the bottom is doing it [The Right Way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32165/double-superscript-error/32171#32171). Given the special service the prime superscript performs (marking out `T'` as an entity distinct from `T`, I'm not sure that this solution isn't in fact better.

Either way, I stick to my suggestion that you should consider using a different variable name.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted my answer explain why?

Comment: Because grouping `{T'}` breaks horizontal placement of subscripts as it puts it in a box of its own with all its side effects, so it is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Thanks. I'm not sure that this is a bad thing in this case. It neatly differentiates the prime from the other sub/superscripts. After all, the prime _ins't_ just another superscript, it's serving a slightly different function…

Comment: Right, I think you have a point here.