# How do I typeset a supersuperscript in LaTeX

Tags: superscripts

I need to type something like `x^{x^x}` in LaTeX, but I keep getting the error

```
! Double superscript.
l.820 ...}(1)_t^{z_{11}}\mathcal{Q}(1)_t^{\prime}^
                                                  {y_{11}}\mathcal{Q}(2)_t^{...
```

How do I get this solved?

Comment: Related: [Double superscript error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32165/5764)

Answer (score 3):

It mostly depends on what you want to achieve; if you want that `y_{11}` is a superscript to the prime, then type `\mathcal{Q}(1)_t^{\prime^{y_{11}}}` (but I suspect it's not what you want). If you want the prime followed by `y_{11}`, then either `\mathcal{Q}(1)_t^{\prime y_{11}}` or, more simply, `\mathcal{Q}(1)_t'^{y_{11}}`.

Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{Q}(1)_t^{\prime^{y_{11}}}$

\medskip

$\mathcal{Q}(1)_t^{\prime y_{11}}$

\medskip

$\mathcal{Q}(1)_t'^{y_{11}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was just stupid. I did the obvious and in this case the obvious doesn't work. You have to group the double exponential not as `x^y^x` but as `x^{y^z}`.

Comment: also `t^{\prime}` is usually (equivalently) written as `t'`

Answer (score 1):

Still another possibility: Write

```
${\mathcal{Q}(1)_t'}^{y_{11}}$
```

i.e., place `\mathcal{Q}(1)_t'` inside curly braces. This raises the `y_{11}` portion a bit relative to the preceding component. Doing this should help create the impression (assuming, of course, that that's what you want) that `y_{11}` is a superscript particle to the formula, rather than co-equal with the prime symbol.

[image]