# Help! Double superscript

Tags: math-mode

What is the problem?

```
\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n} {\beta}{\alpha}(1 - e^{- (x - \mu)\beta}^{\alpha -
  1}e^{- (x - \mu)\beta}
```

I've been trying to change `{\beta}{\alpha}` and `(1 - e^{- (x - \mu)\beta}^{\alpha - 1}`

Comment: It would help if you copied the actual error message, but I think it's complaining about `e^{}^{}`.  (Also, you can use backticks to typeset code, and `{\beta}` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Double superscript.
l.160 ...{\beta}{\alpha}(1 - e^{- (x - \mu)\beta}^
                                                  {\alpha - 1}e^{- (x - \mu)...

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32165/double-superscript-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like some curly brackets are missing:

```
$ \prod_{i=1}^{n} {\beta}{\alpha}(1 - e^{{- (x - \mu)\beta}^{\alpha - 1}}e^{- (x
  - \mu)\beta}$
```