# Why does (my user-defined) command for superscript (inverse) fail next to a prime (quotation) symbol?

Tags: math-mode, macros, superscripts

Minimum working example (I will refer to the lines based on the first letter A-E):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\inv}{^{-1}}
\begin{document}
$A^{-1}$
$B\inv$
$C'^{-1}$
% $D'_1^{-1}$ % fails
% $E'\inv$ % fails
\end{document}
```

I got an error `Double superscript: You have written a double superscript incorrectly as a^b^c, or else you have written a prime with a superscript. Remember to include {and} when using multiple superscripts. Try a^{b ^ c} instead.`

I realise this similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32165/double-superscript-error), but that asks why line D fails.

**My question**: why does line C work but line E fail?

Comment: Try to enclose each element with a curly bracket.

Comment: I was a few seconds faster than egreg :).

Comment: This doesn't explain why (there are already two good explanations for that), but shows an alternate input that *will* work:  `$C^{\prime-1}$`.

Answer (score 10):

The reason is in `plain.tex` file where the `'` is defined at lines 735--739. Other formats (for example LaTeX) copy the same idea.

The `'` is math-active character which runs `^\bgroup\prime` followed by a macro which tests next token by `\futurelet` primitive. If the next token is `'` or `^` then the next superscript is composed with the current superscript and the group (opened by `\bgroup`) isn't closed. But if the next token is another token then `\egroup` is put here and the next token is processed. This is the case of your example `D` (next token is `_`) or `E` (next token is `\inv`).

One nucleus cannot have more than one superscript, so you see the error "double superscript".

If you want to use constructs like `$E'\inv$` or `$E''\inv$`, then you can re-define an internal macro of the format you are using. For example for Plain TeX or LaTeX:

```
{\catcode`\'=\active \catcode`\@=11
 \gdef'{^\bgroup\expandafter\prim@s}\gdef\pr@@@s#1{\expandafter\prim@s}}
```

for OpTeX:

```
{\_catcode`\'=\active \_gdef'{^\_bgroup\_ea\_primes}}
\def\_primesA #1{\_ea\_primes}
```

The idea is to add `\expandafter` before the `\futurelet` is processed. Note that the macro `\prim@s` (or `\_primes`) runs the `\futurelet` primitive.

Comment: Ah thank you this makes sense. Where can I find plain.tex?

Comment: @BenjaminWang The `plain.tex` file is in each TeX distribution. For example, TeX live installs it to `texmf-dist/plain/base/` directory. Or you can find it on your computer using a search tool, for example `locate plain.tex` at Unix-like systems. Of course, you can find it at CTAN site too: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/base

Comment: thank you for the CTAN link, which is helpful for users who don't actually install LaTeX (e.g. by using Overleaf).

Answer (score 9):

When TeX finds `'` (in math mode), it basically does the following:

1. it emits `^\bgroup\prime`;
2. it looks at the following token (without expanding it);
3. if the next token is another `'` it emits `\prime` and returns to step 2;
4. if the next token is `^`, it gobbles it and absorbs what comes next as a macro argument (either a single token or a braced group) and considers it as part of the exponent that's being built and emits `\egroup`;
5. otherwise it emits `\egroup`.

In your case, the next token is `\inv` so this falls into case 5. Thus

```
C'\inv
```

becomes

```
C^\bgroup\prime\egroup\inv
```

and then

```
C^\bgroup\prime\egroup^{-1}
```

Double superscript.

If you want to support this syntax you have to add to the lookup also `\inv`.

All considered, I'd use the syntax `^\inv` instead.

Anyway, here's an `expl3` implementation that supports `\inv`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \wang_prime:
  {
    % start a superscript
    \c_math_superscript_token
    \c_group_begin_token
    % we want a prime
    \prime
    \__wang_prime_next:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__wang_prime_next:
  {
    \peek_charcode_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF '
      { % another ' follows; add it and restart the recursion
        \prime
        \__wang_prime_next:
      }
      { % look for ^ or \inv
        \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \l_peek_token \c_math_superscript_token
          { % remove ^ and add the superscript
            \__wang_prime_remove_superscript:Nn
          }
          {
            \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \l_peek_token \inv
              {
                \__wang_prime_remove_inv:N
              }
              { % finish the business
                \c_group_end_token
              }
          }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__wang_prime_remove_superscript:Nn { #2 \c_group_end_token }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__wang_prime_remove_inv:N { -1 \c_group_end_token }
\char_set_active_eq:NN ' \wang_prime:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\inv}{^{-1}}

\begin{document}

$A^{-1}$

$B\inv$

$C'^{-1}$

$D''^{-1}$

$E'\inv$

\end{document}
```

Note that `a'_{1}^{2}` is not supported and cannot be.

[image]

Comment: Ah so you're suggesting I define `\newcommand{\inv}{{-1}}` and use the syntax `^\inv` instead? Thank you for the detailed explanation. Where is this information documented? It's cool to have the top user answer my first question :D

Comment: @BenjaminWang The code for `'` is described in the TeXbook and is essentially the same in LaTeX.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I added an implementation that supports `\inv`, but you should really consider not using it.

Comment: thank you for the implementation :D I may or may not use it!